# screen resolution stuck at 640*480

Tags: 12.10, resolution, screen

So I installed 12.10 and I am stuck in 640x480 resolution. I cant resize the resolution since the screen wont let me scroll down to see all the settings for screen resolution. can anyone help me out
also a little new to linux

Comment: Since you are not able to see correctly what you are typing/doing, I recommend you to do this step precisely: 1. Open terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T and execute this: `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768` or `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768` Reply what happens..

Answer (score 0):

If you obtained Ubuntu with Gnome, use *CTRL+ALT+T* to open a terminal and execute `sudo gnome-control-center`and click on the Monitor button. Here, if Xorg.conf is well written and you have the correct drivers, you will be able to change your resolution.
(the password for sudo is your account password; if it doesn't work try `su` directly but direct root access is, in general, disabled). Good luck.

Comment: well i got this now GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR_2' on object at path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/XRANDR

Comment: I exprect an upvote man (follow your coscience :) ) From a terminal: `dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr/active true` and if it still doesn't function use `xrandr` from the console or install arandr with `sudo apt-get install arandr` (after that execute it as root from the console with `sudo arandr`).